# get line which start with several spaces and followed by specific character

Tags: regex, grep

The content of my *sample.txt* as below:

```
host$ cat sample.txt
     start from several spaces
start from a-z
    the first ch is t
```

Now, I want to get the line which start with more than one spaces and followed by character **s**. That is to say I want to get the first line.
When I use the command:

```
grep ^[[:space:]]
```

I can get lines start with spaces,the first and end line. However when I change this command into `grep ^[[:space:]]s` I can't get anything.

Comment: @anubhava  I try it just now. but failed.

Comment: Your `grep` may not support `+` so try `grep '^[[:space:]][[:space:]]*s' file`

Comment: So do you want a `grep` solution? `Regex` solution? Either?

Comment: @nailfei: `grep -E '^[[:space:]]+s' file`

Comment: @anubhava thanks, it worked. it seemed that grep dont support some extended regular expressions

Comment: That would find lines that start with 1 or more spaces, not `more than one spaces` as you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

With POSIX grep:

```
grep '^[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]*s' file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]][[:space:]]+s/' file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ grep -E '^[[:space:]]{2,}s' file
     start from several spaces
```